# Firebreath JavaScript error: unsupported: no toString() function in type function

Tags: javascript, browser-plugin, firebreath

I am using the firebreath framework to write a browser plugin. When I use the plugin with javascript I get an weird error:

```
unsupported: no toString() function in type function
```

I get this error wheny I try to call several times a method on my Dropbox_pluginAPI class that returns a JSAPIPtr.

Here is the code:

```
 //JavaScript context
for(var i=0; i<100; i++)
{
//After several times of calling the method I get the error: unsupported: no toString() function in type function
var md = plugin().getMetaDataOfFileOrFolder("dropbox/demotext","null",true,false,"null"); 
}


//API class

FB::JSAPIPtr Dropbox_pluginAPI::getMetaDataOfFileOrFolder(std::string fileOrFolderPath,std::string hash, bool list, bool include_deleted,
std::string rev)
{
MetaData m = client->getMetaDataOfFileOrFolder(fileOrFolderPath,hash,list,include_deleted,rev);

return boost::make_shared<MetaDataAPI>(m_host,m);

}


//MetaDataAPI class
class MetaDataAPI : public FB::JSAPIAuto
{
public:

/**
* Constructor.
* @param host The browser
* @param m The MetaData object
*/
MetaDataAPI(const FB::BrowserHostPtr& host,MetaData m);

.....
.....

}
```

I hope that someone works with firebreath and can help me !

---

I updated the firefox version and seperated pieces into different lines but the error still occurs.
I did the following:

```
var plug = plugin();
var fn = plug.getMetaDataOfFileOrFolder;
var md;
for(var i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    md = fn("dropbox/demotext","null",true,false,"null"); 
}   
alert("Finish");
```

The alert will never be called! There is still the error after some calls:

```
    [unsupported: no toString() function in type function]
```

in line:

```
    md = fn("dropbox/demotext","null",true,false,"null");
```

Comment: Just in case it could help making link, I've also found that bad question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208441/javascript-error-unsupported-no-tostring-function-in-type-function

Comment: ... I think you dod the right thing by reposting a more clear question. I really just wanted to link them, as the comment in the previous one contain some details.

Comment: k I got your intention...thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. First try updating Firefox; there was a bug in an older version of firefox where it would sometimes swap two NPObjects sent across the bridge giving you a different object than you should have.
2. move your plugin() call to a parent scope so you aren't calling it each time
3. seperate pieces of this into different lines so you can see exactly where the error occurs

Like this:

```
var plug = plugin();
for(var i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    var fn = plug.getMetaDataOfFileOrFolder;
    var md = fn("dropbox/demotext","null",true,false,"null"); 
}
```

Assuming the error still occurs, it tells us a lot if it's on the var fn line or the var md line. You could also try moving the var fn line out of the loop and see if that does anything.

If the issue is related to a firefox bug then moving the var fn out will probably make a difference; do those tests and report the results, that may help us figure out what is going on.